# cannot change cursor shape

Tags: python, pyqt, cursor

I am trying to change the shape of the cursor when the right mouse button is pressed over a pushbutton widget on a toolbar. Here's a code snippet:

```
def eventFilter(self, obj, event):  # QEvent
    if isinstance(obj, QPushButton):
        et = event.type()
        if et == QEvent.Type.MouseButtonPress:
            if event.button() == Qt.MouseButton.RightButton:
                cur_cursor = self.toolbar_tables.cursor()  # QCursor
                if cur_cursor.shape() == Qt.CursorShape.ArrowCursor:
                    cur_cursor.setShape(Qt.CursorShape.OpenHandCursor)
                else:
                    cur_cursor.setShape(Qt.CursorShape.ArrowCursor)
                return True
```

The first setShape method is reached, but the second is never reached because the cursor doesn't change, even though the first setShape does correctly change the shape internally. The Qt system seems to work because if I start a drag operation upon a right button press, the cursor changes to a black open hand.

Any ideas, please.

Edit:

```
def eventFilter(self, obj, event):  # QEvent
    if isinstance(obj, QPushButton):
        et = event.type()  # int
        if et == QEvent.Type.MouseButtonPress:
            if event.button() == Qt.MouseButton.RightButton:
                cur_cursor = self.toolbar_tables.cursor()  # QCursor
                if cur_cursor.shape() == Qt.CursorShape.ArrowCursor:
                    cur_cursor.setShape(Qt.CursorShape.OpenHandCursor)
                else:
                    cur_cursor.setShape(Qt.CursorShape.ArrowCursor)
                self.toolbar_tables.setCursor(cur_cursor)
                # QGuiApplication.setOverrideCursor(cur_cursor)
                return True
```

Comment: `cursor.setShape()` only changes the shape of the QCursor, but doesn't change the *widget* cursor. Use [`setCursor()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#cursor-prop) or [`setOverrideCursor()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#setOverrideCursor).

Comment: @musicamante Thank you again for your help. Yes, the QCursor doc does say "To associate a cursor with a widget, use setCursor()". QWidget.cursor() returns a QCursor object; I mistakenly believed it would be a reference to the toolbar cursor, but apparently it is only a copy, which seems to be consistent with many other getters. Hopefully the docs will elaborate in the next iteration.

Comment: @musicamante Your solution does give me the open hand cursor, but the moment I move that cursor off the pushbutton, the cursor reverts to the original arrow, even though the cursor remains within the toolbar. setOverrideCursor is not appropriate because the open hand will persist outside the toolbar. I have added an edit to show the new attempt.

Comment: It's not clear for what widgets you want to set the cursor, and for how long. Should the cursor remain while the mouse button is pressed, or even after it's released? And do you want to set the cursor only for the toolbar (and all its buttons) or something else? Please provide a [mre], so that we can also understand what type of objects are you dealing with.